# Find entry without a cursor in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, cursor, nosql

Im using mongodb and java. There is a function login, this function is checking the db for a mail and fit password. If there is no one then return false, if yes then true:

```
boolean login(String email, String password) {

    /**/

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("email", email);
    query.put("password", password);

    DBCollection collection = c.getDatabase().getCollection("...");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

    if (cursor.size() > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I have the feeling that this function looks ugly ^^ Is there a better way to code this in java? Avoid a curos? Well its working but there could be a better way as `cursor.size()` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works in Java, however, the findOne() method should return a single document or null if there is no such document.

Comment: Yes but the problem with findOne() is that I cannot search for two keys and compare them for the same document (as it should be for a login) - or I have no idea how to code it in Java ;). Help

Comment: why? db.loginCollection.findOne( { 'email' : 'myEmail', 'password' : 'myPass' } );  you will get a document or None.